# Why EAX register content suddenly changed and leads to crash

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-64, race-condition, cpu-registers

In the following screenshot you can see the disassembly of the CString function `GetLength()` which lead to a crash. This is taken from the dumpfile, post mortem. The crash is caused by a sudden change of register EAX to 0.

How can it be that from 6A6A4547 to 6A6A4549 the register EAX could be changed. In 6A6A4547 it should have been set to 0x6a8e7054 (0x38324964 {0x6a8e7054}). You can see this in the watch window. In 6A6A4549 EAX is suddenly "0".

Why and How? Can I find out what was the cause?

Side information:

- call stack looks normal no problems in variables or threads
- its compiled with VS2012 compiler
- target platform is x86
- its on a virtual machine
- program runs with many threads
- GetLength is called millions of times per hour

[image: graph]

Comment: And this happens completely randomly? Did you catch it live while running it in a debugger or is this screenshot based on a core dump?

Comment: Note the `[eax-0ch]`, specifically the **-0ch** part. See what's in `0x38324958`.

Comment: (int*) (0x38324958) -> 0x38324958 {0x00000000}
This is actually the correct value (its an empty string). The problem is that eax is 0x0000000 and instead of "0x38324958" the value "-12" is used as adress.

Comment: I guess `GetData()` returns a nullptr?! What happens if you add something like `if (GetData()) return GetData()->nDataLength; else ...`

Comment: @Matti Virkkunen: It happened after 5 days running the server application. Its a screenshot of the dumpfile. The same call stack runs ~10000 times per minute.

Comment: @Elijan9: "GetData()->nDataLength" is replaced by the compiler with the given two lines of assembler. The problem is that EAX is suddenly 0 after it was set to "0x6a8e7054" which is the value unreferenced from ecx.

Comment: Perhaps it ran out of memory? Failed to allocate data, the data pointer is 0, and GetData() returns 0

Comment: Maybe a race condition? The Watch window may get out of sync if another thread write to the same memory.

Comment: @Margaret Bloom: Also the memory windows shows the correct value. How can the EAX register be overwritten?

Comment: Perhaps another the value pointed to by `ecx` was zero when the first `mov` ran, and it was changed to the valid value between them by another thread. Either that, or the watch isn't working correctly.

Comment: @Kalman I was talking about the memory being overwritten. Post the full information, as it is standing it's not clear what are you doing, checking, or expecting. EAX can end up being zero given the code.

Comment: After reading your response to @Margaret Bloom, I think your disassembly should be : mov eax,ecx bcoz in next instruction u want to read the content of the address 0x38324964-0xc, whereas, after executing mov eax, dword ptr [ecx] the next instruction would read  the content of 0x6a837054-0xc and this could potentially raise an invalid read address violation. I trust you will be able to make the necessary changes to the corresponding C program

Comment: @Kalman: Don't focus on the AEX register. It would never make sense that eax suddenly becomes 0 after it was set to 0x6a8e7054. Much more likely, the problem is that the variable holding the pointer returned by GetData() contained 0 during the execution of that statement and by the time your debugger was triggered, it was already holding a different value (0x6a8e7054). In other words, you are facing a race condition.

Comment: In the future, it would be helpful to post a complete call stack. The dump gives you this information, and it would certainly have been helpful here, as the problem is in code higher up the chain. And preferably post this information in text form, rather than as a picture...

Answer (score 2):

It is as most of you wrote - [a race condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition#Software).

In a more upper part of the software an object was not locked sufficiently.
Therefore EAX became 0 in the first assembly line. After that another thread "corrected" the memory and it only looks like the EAX register has been changed.

So as most of the crashes also this is homemade.

Thanks to all of you!